# regex to exact match 11 digit phone number from string and remove hyphen(-) from match in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms

I am creating a text parser in c# windows form and I want to identify 11 digit phone numbers starting from 0 with a **-** separator, eg 0341-2239548 or 021-34223311 should be converted to 03412239548 and 02134223311 respectively using Regex.Match. I am unable to find the relevant regex expression, can anyone help me please?

string[] RemoveCharacter = { "\"", "(", ")", "/=", "/", ":-", ":", ";", "-" };

```
        foreach (string word in RemoveCharacter)
        {
            s = s.Replace(word, " ");
        }
```

after removing these characters, phone numbers are also separated by a space and I do not want that to happen only for phone numbers.

Comment: So given a string starting with a '0' and containing 10 more digits and optionally some separators, you want to retain only the digits? Why do you need a regex for that? What if an input string contains multiple separators? At what positions can they occur? What if it contains no separators at all? Can it contain whitespace? Don't you just want to extract 11 digits when a string contains that many, and otherwise reject the input?

Comment: Actually in the previous step, I have removed the - so now there is space between the first and second half of the two parts of the number, how do i concatenate them?

Comment: this question is getting down voting, for more than a reason. As a start, [this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) (and nocode would be the next)
Have a look at [ask]

Comment: Please provide some code that you've tried already

Comment: Might want to have a look here first: [Regex Tutorials](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: `var formattedNumber = number.Replace("-", String.Empty)`

Comment: No I have the fully functional code, which I can provide, this is the first time I am asking a question on any platform, so please do not get offended.
My code is here: 
string[] RemoveCharacter = { "\"", "(", ")", "/=", "/", ":-", ":", ";", "-" };
             
            
            foreach (string word in RemoveCharacter)
            {
                s = s.Replace(word, " ");
            }
Now I need to remove the "-" but after that, the phone no is split into 2, which makes it to 2 no's and I need to count the total no of words in the user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below Regex to remove all hyphens and all other non numeric characters from phone number

```
string pattern = @"\b([\-]?\d[\-]?){11}\b";

Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

var sentence = "This is phone number 0341-2239548 and 021-34223311";

var matches = rgx.Matches(sentence);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    string replacedValue = Regex.Replace(match.Value, @"[^0-9]", "");
    sentence = sentence.Replace(match.Value, replacedValue);
}
```

See the **[demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H90ion)**

Comment: This even works for number greater than 10-11 digits, eg if there is a no such as 42201-46988-023 i do not want to remove the -, this should only work for phone numbers in a string.

Comment: ok means if your string contains 11 digit phone number then and then only replace "-" ?

Comment: @FatimaKhalid, I updated my answer to match, all the occurrences of 11 digit phone numbers in your entire string and replaced its hyphen with empty string.

Comment: @FatimaKhalid, i used `Regex.Matches` that you want and also see the updated demo:)

Comment: @FatimaKhalid, if you want to match 10 or 11 digit then use `{10, 11}` in above pattern.

Comment: @FatimaKhalid, glad to hear and welocme :)

Answer (score 0):

if you have a string like that, just remove your seperator. You dont need a regex for that:

```
string nr = "0154-1452146";
nr = nr.Replace("-", "");
Console.WriteLine(nr);
```

Comment: Actually i have a whole string with no in between and i want to replace "-" everywhere except between no's.

Comment: @FatimaKhalid So basically you have something like this "abc-def-ghi-jkl-0147-852369-mno-pqr-stu"
And you want "abc def ghi jkl 0147-852369 mno pqr stu" or "abcdefghijkl0147-852369mnopqrstu"? Its not clear from your question. Please provide examples.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.